# Testing if command is in cooldown

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

If my the command is currently in cooldown when someone tries to do the command, I just want to send a message to the player saying that the command is in cooldown.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def cooldown_test(ctx):
    await bot.say("Hello!")
    # If the bot is on cooldown then:
    # await bot.say("On cooldown!")
```

This is an answer abccd wrote on a duplicate.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot('$')

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, content='This command is on a %.2fs cooldown' % error.retry_after)
    raise error  # re-raise the error so all the errors will still show up in console


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 30)
async def getalt(ctx):
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, content='in getalt')

bot.run('token')
```

Comment: The [changeset implementing cooldown support](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/commit/cd0de57d13b15f709aaacf78ce611dd87e0784ce) is informative. See the CommandOnCooldown exception, in particular.

Comment: I used "try:" the code and "except CommandOnCooldown:" and the bot.say but nothing happens.

Comment: *nod*, the `raise CommandOnCooldown` is no longer there in master. Details of which specific library version you're using (which it looks like the question doesn't include) matter. (That said, maybe you might read the source yourself?)

Comment: there is a specific [`on_command_error`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L286) event that you can use. You just need to check if `CommandOnCooldown` was raised. Remember to reraise the error if it isn't though...

Comment: Adding "Solved" to the title of your question is **strictly against site policy** and undermines the point of accepted answers. Please don't do this.